# Passport: Can I stay authenticated while working on code?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, passport.js, nodemon

I've just implemented a login system for the web app I'm working on, but now every time I update my code, I have to re-log in to test it. I'm using Nodemon, Passport, Node, Express, EJS, Mongoose, and MongoDB. I need to be able to access data from MongoDB still, so I would have to be authenticated as some user.

The basic path is: `homepage => login => dashboard(based on user's mongodb data)`

How can I work around the authentication so I can keep reloading the dashboard as the same authenticated user without adding unnecessary code?

Comment: How are you keeping track of the authentication state? Cookie based session? Javascript code on the front-end saving tokens in localStorage?

Comment: I'm using Local Strategy with passport. Does that answer your question? (I'm very new to passport)